# Generating Function for Associated Stirling Numbers $b(n,k)$

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, power-series, generating-functions

I am trying to identify or find the ordinary generating function (not the exponential generating function) for the Associated Stirling numbers of the Second kind, denoted $$b(1;n,k)=b(n,k)$$
These numbers are the number of ways to partition a set of $n$ elements into $k$ disjoint parts whose partition cardinality are greater than 1.
If there isn't already an explicit formula, how I do go about attempting to derive such a thing?

EDIT:
One thing that I do know is that 
$$b(n,j)=\sum_{k=0}^j(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}S(n-k,j-k)$$
where $S(n,k)$ are Stirling numbers of the second kind.  Therefore, I can say that 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty b(n,j)x^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=0}^j(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}S(n-k,j-k)\right)x^n$$
which is quite ugly.  I also know that the Stirling Numbers of the Second kind have the ordinary generating function
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty S(n,k)x^n=\frac{x^k}{(1-x)(1-2x)...(1-kx)}  $$
which I'm hoping to take advantage of after some brute force calculation...

EDIT 2:  Aftr some brute force calculation, it appears that I have a series generated, that looks like
$$b(n,j)=\sum_{k=0}^j(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}S(n-k,j-k)$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty b(n,j)x^n=b(0,j)+b(1,j)+b(2,j)+b(3,j)+b(4,j)+...$$
Now
$$b(0,j)=1$$
$$b(1,j)=S(1,j)$$
$$b(2,j)=S(2,j)-2S(1,j-1)$$
$$b(3,j)=S(3,j)-3S(2,j-1)$$
$$b(4,j)=S(4,j)-4S(3,j-1)+6S(2,j-2)$$
$$b(5,j)=S(5,j)-5S(4,j-1)+10S(3,j-2)$$
$$b(6,j)=S(6,j)-6S(5,j-1)+15S(4,j-2)-20(3,j-3)$$
$$b(7,j)=S(7,j)-7S(6,j-1)+21S(5,j-2)-35(4,j-3)$$
$$... $$
Rearranging I can see that I have
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty b(n,j)x^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty S(n,j)x^n-\sum_{n=1}^\infty nS(n-1,j-1)x^n+\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n(n-1)}{2!}S(n-2,j-2)x^n-\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}S(n-3,j-3)x^n+...$$
And it looks like a derivative is taking effect but my powers of $x$ are not changing, but it also looks like I'm running in circles.  I feel like my bounds are incorrect...Should, for example, I change
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nS(n-1,j-1)x^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)S(n,j-1)x^{n+1}$$
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n(n-1)}{2!}S(n-2,j-2)x^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{2!}S(n,j-2)x^{n+2}$$
Any suggestions?

EDIT 3:  By comparing the first few numbers given $j$ values 2,3,4, there seems to be a trend, the generating function is structured 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b(n,j)x^n=\frac{f(x)}{\prod_{k=1}^{j}(1-kx)^{j-k+1}}$$
The degree of the numerator is greater than the degree of the denominator in the cases where $j=2,3,4$ and the ratios of degree(numerator) to degree(denominator) for $j=2,3,4$ are $$\frac{4}{3}, \frac{9}{6}, \frac{14}{10}$$

EDIT 4:  I found a paper that gives me an exponential generating function of the form:

$$\sum_{n,k\ge 1}b(n,k)u^k\frac{t^n}{n!}=\exp{(u\exp{(1-Q(2,t)}})$$
where $Q(2,t)=\frac{\Gamma(2,t)}{\Gamma(2)}$
I found the paper, and never wrote down the author or journal.  Any help would be amazing!